# Calling an assembly language function into a c program

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

This assignment asks me to write my own function a file called diff.s that takes one argument, calls function2 with the same argument, and returns what function2 returns, minus the passed-in
argument. For example, if diff is called 5 it should return 20 = 5*5-5

I need help on how to write the assembly language as every time I try I get a segmentation fault.

```
//gcc -g callC-AL-C.c diff.s -o callC-AL-C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int diff(int);

int function1(int number) {
    int returnValue = diff(number) + 7;
    return returnValue;
}

int function2(int number) {
    return number*number;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int argument1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d\n",function1(argument1));

    return 0;
}
```

the assembly language diff.s only has 5 lines:

```
    .global diff
diff:
    pushq   %rdi
    movl    %rax, %rbp
    subl    %rax, %eax
    call    function2
    ret
```

table of registers we must use the right-hand column

```
Callee must restore           Callee may change
%rbp                          %rax
%rsp                          %rcx 
%rbx                          %rdx
                              %rsi
                              %rdi
%r12-%r15                     %r8-%r11
```

Comment: Have you tried writing that function in C and then look at the generated code?

Comment: Never thought of doing that thanks I will try to do that

Comment: Online https://godbolt.org/

Comment: The immediately visible problem appears to be that your `diff` function pushes a value onto the stack but doesn't bother to pop it off.  This'll cause the return to go to an unexpected address, crashing your program.

Comment: Also `diff` copies the incoming RAX to call-preserved RBP for no reason.  And uses  `movl` (32-bit) which conflicts with the 64-bit register names, so it doesn't even assemble.  And `subl %rax, %eax` also won't assemble: the source operand doesn't match the destination size.  Was that supposed to be `sub %eax,%eax` to zero EAX?  You don't need to do that; `function2` isn't variadic so it doesn't need AL=number of FP args (max 8), i.e. number of XMM registers with FP args.